# Positioning a moving image/rect with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to position my `image and rect`, but they are already moving back and forth. Can I still manually position their start point at this stage, when they are already on the move?

Currently the Image bounces back and forth on the screen. I would like to position the start point of this motion to an arbitrary point, say `(0,100)` of my window. Is there a way to set this positioning of my `image and rect` so that it can keep it's movement but just start from another point? Currently it's stuck on the top, I've tried a few things that didn't work:

```
    self.image = pygame.image.load('picture.jpg')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

---

```
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.rect.move_ip(5,0)           #only moving on the x axis

        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > self.width:         
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]

        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Is there a way where I can set a starting position for my Surface object and rectangle?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Just do

```
 self.rect.move_ip(0, 100)
```

to move to `(0,100)`.

See [the pygame.Rect docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.move) for more.

Comment: I see, this can allow me to instantiate the `self.rect.move_ip(0,100)` at `(0,100)` and still be able to keep the motion in draw.